# "To edit iOS storyboards, you can use Xcode on a Mac"

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I updated Visual Studio today, and apparently as of Version 16.9, we can no longer edit iOS storyboards how we used to.  The message that is shown in VS (see title) links off to this page:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/storyboards/#creating-a-storyboard-with-xcode.  That's great and all, but all this does is show us how to open the files from VS on a Mac.   Is there any built in way to send a storyboard file over to the Mac for editing, or do I need to manually transfer the file and any resources/images I need to reference?  I suppose I could install Git on the Mac and pull down the whole project, but then I would need to commit my untested storyboard updates in order to test them on Windows.  Are we better off just developing on the Mac then?  A 5 minute update to a storyboard has led us to have to reconsider our entire development strategy.  Hopefully someone out there has some good news for us!

**UPDATE**

In an effort to move this along, we have installed GitHub on our cloud Mac, pulled down the project and followed the instructions on opening the storyboard in Xcode from VS for Mac.  When attempting to open the storyboard, we receive the message "Visual Studio could not communicate with Xcode".  I haven't found much information on how to resolve this issue, but what I have found (reinstalling Xcode) is not an option for us.  I will update again if we ever figure out a solution for us.  For what it's worth, we are using a shared Macincloud.com cloud Mac.

**UPDATE 2**

We were able to start editing storyboards once we purchased a Dedicated Macincloud mac (instead of Managed/shared).  Even so, updating the storyboards in Xcode is a big learning curve and we would prefer to stay in our Windows environment if at all possible.  We have requested the reimplementation of the storyboard editor in VS here:  https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14148

Comment: If you use storyboards frequently, developing on the Mac is a good choose, You can add a feature request about this needs as well: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/new/choose

Comment: I personally prefect editing them in Xcode because Apple always introducing new features in their Storyboard designer which could either lag behind or not present in VS Editor.